# Failed to handle method call java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported, use openfile

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I get this error in any dart file that containing **TextFormField** or **TextField** .

and please note that I don't use SQLite and I remove the app and reinstall it again and the same issue ,any help .

```
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported, use openfile
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:698)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1465)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1409)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:337)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.access$700(PlatformPlugin.java:28)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin$1.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:107)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformChannel.java:141)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform(16213):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

flutter --version output

```
Flutter 1.17.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b041144f83 (1 year, 1 month ago) • 2020-06-04 09:26:11 -0700
Engine • revision ee76268252
Tools • Dart 2.8.4
```

pubspec.yaml

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  encrypt: ^3.3.1
  http: ^0.12.0+1
  unique_identifier: ^0.0.3
  device_info: ^1.0.0
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  onesignal_flutter: ^2.0.0
  adobe_xd: ^1.0.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.3
  url_launcher: ^5.5.0
  expandable_card: ^0.0.3+1
  package_info: ^0.4.0+16
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+14
  date_time_picker:
  expandable: ^4.1.4
  screen: ^0.0.5
  intl: ^0.17.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

Flutter Doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1879], locale en-US)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: did you try `flutter clean` ?

Comment: the issue goes out without any change, its weird.!